# How to keep data temporarily between views and controllers in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am having  a situation webgrid in a partial view, and I want to maintain the same model data  until final submission.

Please find the the scenario with code,

**View : Index.cshtml**

```
function GetFilter() {

    var url = "/Student/SelectStudentByRollNO/?rollno=1";
     var value = $('#rollno').val();



     $.ajax({
         url: url,
         type: 'GET',
         cache: false,
         data: { rollno : value },
         success: function (FeeRemaining) {
             $('#gridContent').html(FeeRemaining);
         }
     });



}



@Html.TextBox("rollno")
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Get filter" onclick="javascript: GetFilter();" />
```

**Here I am binding partial view in the gridcontent div id**

**Partial View : _studentGrid.cshtml**

```
<div>

@{

var gd = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5, selectionFieldName:    "selectedRow",ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
    gd.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);}




        @gd.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table",
                headerStyle: "head",
                alternatingRowStyle: "altRow",
                selectedRowStyle: "selectRow",
                columns: gd.Columns(
                gd.Column("RollNo", "RollNo"),
                gd.Column("Name", " Name"),
                gd.Column("Branch", "Branch", style: "description"),
                gd.Column("FeeRemaining", "FeeRemaining"),
                gd.Column(header: "Delete",format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("DeleteStudent",    "Student", new { rollno = item.RollNo })" onclick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure would you like to delete this Student?');">Delete</a></text>)
          ))


</div>
```

**Model**

```
public class StudentClass {
    public string RollNo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Branch { get; set; }
    public long FeeRemaining { get; set; }
}
```

controller & action result

```
public class StudentController : Controller {
    //
    // GET: /Student/

    public ActionResult Index() {

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SelectStudentByRollNO(int rollno)
    {
        List<StudentClass> lststudent = new List<StudentClass>();
        lststudent.Add(new StudentClass { RollNo = "08330001", Name = "Surbhi", Branch = "C.S", FeeRemaining = 18000 });
        lststudent.Add(new StudentClass { RollNo = "08330004", Name = "Arun", Branch = "C.S", FeeRemaining = 2500 });
        lststudent.Add(new StudentClass { RollNo = "08329006", Name = "Ankita", Branch = "I.T", FeeRemaining = 31000 });

        ViewBag.lst_student = lststudent;

        return PartialView("_studentGrid", lststudent);

    }

    public ActionResult DeleteStudent(string rollno)
    {

        List<StudentClass> FeeRemaining = new List<StudentClass>();


        return PartialView("_studentGrid", FeeRemaining);
    }
}
```

in the above Delete DeleteStudent Action result I want all the original data...

Thanks in advance
muni

Comment: Dear, @user3251962, why have you tagged this question with **"java"**? Java has as much in common with JavaScript, as car has with carpet.

Answer (score 0):

If you render the original data on the clients browser and then send it back to the server you would have to validate it all as the user could have changed anything before posting it back to you. Never trust data that has been to the browser and back. It looks like you want to be accessing a data store (such as a database) in your "SelectStudentByRollNO" call. After you have deleted the data you could then call:

```
return RedirectToAction("SelectStudentByRollNO", new { rollno = 99 });
```

This would return the result of SelectStudentByRollNO.

As an aside you may want to change "rollno" on "DeleteStudent" to an int to match "SelectStudentByRollNO".

Comment: Hi Andrew,  Thanks for the reply.. finally I used session object for temporary storage of values